# Why the "Manage Nuget Packages" window still offers updating a project if its version is constrained?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I have a project which references `Selenium` packages. In the near past they released the `3.0` branch, but I don't want to upgrade, and want to stay at the `2.0` branch. So I updated my `packages.config` file this way

```
<package id="Selenium.Support" version="2.53.1" allowedVersions="(,3)" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Selenium.WebDriver" version="2.53.1" allowedVersions="(,3)" targetFramework="net45" />
```

However, I still see the offered updates to `3.0.1` versions in the "Manage Nuget Packages..." window's "Updates" tab.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1094) in previous version of NuGet Package Manager, but it has been fixed.

Please Update NuGet Package Manager to version 3.5, which works fine in my side. You could download it from below link.

https://dist.nuget.org/index.html

Comment: I have NuGet version 3.5.0.1484, sorry I didn't mention that in the post.

Comment: My NuGet Package Manager version is 3.5.0.1996, which should be higher than yours. Please uninstall your 3.5.0.1484 from Visual Studio 2015 Tools menu -> Extensions and Updates and then download the latest version from the link I provided.

Comment: I'll never understand the soul of VS extensions update notifications... I have a checkmark what says "This extension updates automatically" or so.

Comment: I've manually updated it as you suggested, and indeed it works now as expected, thank you.